# Usage of Primary and Foreign keys in an EER diagram

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, eer-model

In my db I have three tables (I have more but for case is equal, users can be companies or single people).

- `Users` has a primary key `id_user`;
- `Company` has a primary key `id_company` and a foreign key `users_id_user`;
- `job_offers` has a primary key `id_job_offers` and two foreign keys: `company_id_company` and `company_users_id_user`.

My questions are:

1. Does a primary key make sense in `job_offers`? I don't think that there is a reason for it.
2. `job_offers` has two foreign keys, one related to `company` and other to `users`. Is there a problem with this? Does there exist another way to accomplish the same task?

[image: EER]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does a primary key make sense in
>   job_offers? I don't think that there
>   is a reason for it.

Yes . I agree that every table should have their own PK. 
[Should each and every table have a primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840162/should-each-and-every-table-have-a-primary-key)

> I have more but for case is equal,
>   users can be companies or single
>   people
>
> job_offers has two foreign keys, one
>   related to company  and other to
>   users. Is there a problem with this?
>   Does there exist another way to
>   accomplish the same task?
>
> The system have two types of users:
>   normal user (person) and company user.
>   The  job_offers is a table that save
>   job offers from a company. If a
>   company user want to post a job , a
>   record will be inserted to the
>   job_offers table . Then once the
>   normal user get this job offer , the
>   job_offers.company_user_id_user will
>   be assigned to this normal user 's 
>   userid.

But from your ER diagram , `Company.users_id_user` is the PK , which cannot be null , and this PK is used in the `job_offers.company_users_id_user` as a FK. So `job_offers.company_users_id_user` also cannot be null .

As a result , it cannot handle the situation that a company user just  post a job and before a normal user gets this job offer or no one gets this job offer eventually  .In this case,  `job_offers.company_users_id_user` should set to null , which violates the `job_offers.company_users_id_user` 's not null constraint.

I will accomplish the same task  using this design:

```
Users
=================
id_user (PK)
email 
activation
password

Company
=================
id_company (PK)
activities 
foundation 
user_id (FK to Users)
description

job_offer
=================
id_job_offer (PK)
id_company (FK to Company)
description_offer 
tags

user_offer
=================
id (PK)
user_id (FK to Users)
job_offer_id (FK to job_offer)
```

Comment: the job_offers is a table that save job offers from a company. Like:  Job: designer, job: commercial director. The system have two types of users: normal user (person) and company user.

Comment: Then , what is job_offers.company_user_id_user means? Does it mean if a company user want to post a job , a record will be inserted to the job_offers table . Then once the normal user get this job offer , the job_offers.company_user_id_user will be assigned to this normal user 's userid?

Comment: Then your design cannot handle the situation when a company user just post a job and before a normal user gets this job offer or no one gets this job offer eventually . I have updated my answer to handle this situation. :)

Answer (score 2):

All tables should have a primary key.  It sounds like you are asking whether your primary key should be a *surrogate key* or a *natural key*.

You might ask the same question of your other tables as well.  For instance, assuming the *email* column in your *users* table is required and unique, it could be used as a (natural) primary key.

This question is pretty heavily debated, and both approaches can work (as can a mixed approach).  If you want to read up on this subject in general, do a google search for "Natural vs. Surrogate Key".

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you're right. There is no need for a separate `id` field there. The two foreign keys should, together, make up the table's primary key.
2. Looks fine to me.

Comment: at the moment, the primary key of the table job_offers is composed by id_job_offers, company_id_company and company_users_id_user

Comment: @Fel: OK. If you removed `id_job_offers` then of course that'd come out of the `PRIMARY KEY` too.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) make sense a primary key in
>   job_offers? I think there is no reason

Yes there is - every table ought to have a primary key.  It's called 'normalization.'

Your choice might not be very good.  I'd say that the two foreign keys together should be the primary key, not the id column.

> 2) The job offers have two foreign
>   keys, one related to company and other
>   to users, any problem ? exists another
>   way (best way) to make this?

No, that's how many-to-many relationships are done.

Comment: Tables having a `PRIMARY KEY` is not normalisation (though, looking at the scenario from the other direction, it's difficult to do normalisation without one).

Comment: the table have a primary key that is composed by company_id_company and company_users_id_user. So, i can delete the id, correct?

Comment: @Tomalek.  Normalization is not a one step process.  The first step is to ensure keyed access to all data.  This can't be acheived without guaranteeing that no two rows will contain the same data.  A primary key is one way to make that guarantee.  So it is a step towards normalization.