# MySQL Tables with Temp Data - Include a Primary Key?

Tags: mysql

I'm putting together a new database and I have a few tables that contain temp data.

e.g.: user requests to change password - a token is stored and then later removed.

Currently I have a primary key on these tables that will auto-increment from 1 upwards.

```
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

I don't really see any use for this primary key... I will never reference it and it will just get larger.

Should tables like this have a primary key or not?

Comment: Which is your engine?

Answer (score 0):

> Short answer: yes.
>
> Long answer:
>
> You need your table to be joinable on something If you want your table
> to be clustered, you need some kind of a primary key. If your table
> design does not need a primary key, rethink your design: most
> probably, you are missing something. Why keep identical records? In
> MySQL, the InnoDB storage engine always creates a PRIMARY KEY if you
> didn't specify it explicitly, thus making an extra column you don't
> have access to.
>
> Note that a PRIMARY KEY can be composite.
>
> If you have a many-to-many link table, you create the PRIMARY KEY on
> all fields involved in the link. Thus you ensure that you don't have
> two or more records describing one link.
>
> Besides the logical consistency issues, most RDBMS engines will
> benefit from including these fields in an UNIQUE index.
>
> And since any PRIMARY KEY involves creating a UNIQUE index, you should
> declare it and get both logical consistency and performance.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840182/1029330) is a SO thread already have same discussion.

Some people still loves to go with your opinion. Have a look [here](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081029141336AAECAnF)

My personal opinion is that you should have primary keys, to identify or to make a row unique. The logic can be your program logic. Can be an auto-increment or composite or whatever it can be.