# Table without logical primary key

Tags: sql, database, primary-key

I've read similar questions both on Google and stackoverflow, for example, this thread  [Should each and every table have a primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840162/should-each-and-every-table-have-a-primary-key) and I   understand it's generally a good idea to have a primary key in every table.

I'm now trying to create a simple table, it stores end of day prices for a list of stocks, so it has three columns: stock ticker, date and price. Apparently none of these three columns are unique and to use the table I'll need to join on both date and stock ticker (I have a unique constrain on that). Of course, I can add another surrogate id column just for the sake of having a primary key, but I just want to check if this is an acceptable design or there're better ways to model the data I'm storing?

Many thanks.

Comment: There's no rule that primary keys can't be composites. It sounds like you've already identified the logical PK - `{ticker, date}`.

Comment: Oh..thanks Damien...I was just being stupid :)