# SQL Find smallest unique key in table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with 8 columns and would like to know the smallest possible unique key for this table. (there are no indexes).

This is as distinct as it gets:

```
select count(*) 
  from (select distinct id1, id2, id3, 
                        id4, id5, id6, 
                        id7, id8 
          from mytable);
```

Is there a quick and easy way to figure out what column combination is unique for this table? How to proceed?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Any answer you get will be dependent on the data that happens to be loaded at the time. Any change made to the table could invalidate the result, so what's the point?

Comment: Oracle 11g. We want to introduce uniqueness from this point onwards. So if in future some insert may harm the key, this wouldn't be an issue but enforcing the uniqueness

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in to work this out in most database systems - there are 255 possible combinations of columns (assuming a zero column key isn't a possibility) - and you'd need to define what metric you're using for smallest - are you attempting to minimize space used or the number of columns? (Because those metrics could be in opposition)

Comment: by smallest I mean number of cols in key to make it unique. eg. if combination id1, id4, id5 does fullfull the uniqueness, it would be the smallest combination, id1, id4, id5, id6 would therefore also be unique, but not the smallest possible combination.

Comment: The only way to really answer this is to know *what* the data represents. i.e. you'll need to do some actual analysis work.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no quick and easy way as people have said; as [Barmar commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458002/sql-find-smallest-unique-key-in-table#comment27126291_18458002):

> Any answer you get will be dependent on the data that happens to be loaded at the time. Any change made to the table could invalidate the result

Additionally you have not previously had a primary key searching for uniqueness could easily come up with a false positive. You haven't been enforcing uniqueness so the set of columns that *should* be unique might not be.

A unique key is determined by the *data* within your table. You need to understand the data in order to determine what should be unique.

There should be a [natural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key) way of having a unique key, i.e. if you've got a table of OS users then the unique key should probably be their username. Equally, if you have a table of employees there's no way to guarantee uniqueness across employee name (or any other attribute or set of attributes) so you will need to create a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key).

Only you can determine this; study your data and you should be able to work it out.

Generally:

- [Every table should have a primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840162/should-each-and-every-table-have-a-primary-key); should should be created at the same time as the table.
- There is nothing more important than understanding the data within your database. You are not able to effectively use the database until you understand what it is that you're looking at.