# ORA-00922: missing or invalid option when creating table

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table Consulting Project(
             ID           varchar(4) not null,
             Name         varchar(5) not null,
             Gender       varchar(1) not null,
             Job_Title    varchar(15) not null,
             Contribution number(1,0) not null
)
```

and got

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Comment: you simply put single quotes before and after name .your issue is resolve

Comment: @ManishSingh good approach, but double quotes as `"Consulting Project"`

Comment: But space is not a good habits .you should use _(underscore).

Answer (score 5):

Some notes.  I would suggest:

```
create table ConsultingProject(
         ID           varchar2(4) primary key,
         Name         varchar2(5) not null,
         Gender       varchar2(1) not null,
         Job_Title    varchar2(15) not null,
         Contribution number(1,0) not null
);
```

Notes:

- Your problem is the space in the table name.  Just make it one word
- Oracle recommends `varchar2` instead of `varchar`.
- Declaring a primary key is a good idea for a table.
- The scale and precision are not needed on `number`.  Perhaps you just want `char(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

That because the space in the table name.
You can change it to

```
create table Consulting_Project(
             ID           varchar(4) not null,
             Name         varchar(5) not null,
             Gender       varchar(1) not null,
             Job_Title    varchar(15) not null,
             Contribution number(1,0) not null
)
```

OR

```
create table "Consulting Project"(
             ID           varchar(4) not null,
             Name         varchar(5) not null,
             Gender       varchar(1) not null,
             Job_Title    varchar(15) not null,
             Contribution number(1,0) not null
)
```

a beside not, it's bad idea to create a table without a `Primay Key` cause every table should have a `Primary Key`

> Why?

Well, the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840182/6426692)