# Will Entity Framework create models for the tables which do not have primary key?

Tags: entity-framework, model

In ASP.NET MVC, for creating of models with Entity Framework, is a primary key on the tables mandatory?

Comment: Not just for EF - a table that holds actual data should ***always*** have a proper primary key.

Comment: ASP.Net MVC and Entity Framework are completely separate frameworks.  There is no reason for this question to include ASP.Net MVC.

Answer (score 0):

No. Each and every should table have a primary key!

See explain here:

[Should each and every table have a primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840162/should-each-and-every-table-have-a-primary-key)