# Which sql index to use on my table for best query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have the following table. My stored procedure always uses IitemId and Created date range.
**Where ItemId = ... and Created > ... and Created < ....**
What would be the best design for performance.

I have a non-clustered index on **ItemId**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LV] (
[Id]       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
[ItemId]   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
[C1]  NVARCHAR (7)     NOT NULL,
[C2] NVARCHAR (7)     NOT NULL,
[C3]  NVARCHAR (2)     NOT NULL,
[Created]  DATETIME2 (7)    NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_LV] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_LV_Items_ItemId] FOREIGN KEY ([ItemId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Items] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LV_ItemId]
ON [dbo].[LV]([ItemId] ASC);
```

Should I add indexes to ItemId and Created? 
Non-clustered or clustered?

Comment: It is not related to your question, but it is performance related. It is really, [really bad practice to use a non-sequential unique identifier as your clustering key.](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/).

Comment: Or more reading - [More considerations for the clustering key – the clustered index debate continues!](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/more-considerations-for-the-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-continues/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the query you have in mind, you want a composite index on `(itemId, created)`.

This works because the condition on `itemId` is equality, so the inequality will use the second key in the index.

A clustered index could help, depending on the nature of the data.  If an item is only stored one or two or three times in the table, then a clustered index will probably not be of much use.  If an item is stored many times, then the rows for the item will be spread through the table and a clustered index would help.

There are even caveats to that.  If the table is used frequently and is fully loaded into the data pages, then a clustered index would help but not be as beneficial as when the table is too big to fit into available memory.

Answer (score 0):

If your only performance concern is that stored procedure, then yes,  you should make the clustered index on `ItemId` and `Created`.

Comment: Except that ItemId is a uniqueidentifier so clustering on that is going to lead to horrific fragmentation.

Comment: @SeanLange nothing a nightly maintenance plan can't handle, unless this table's data is getting modified hundreds of thousands of times a day...

Comment: GarethD's linked article up in the comments has a lot of good information, which can help make a decision to whether the OP should continue with a clustered GUID PK or not. It was a great read!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tab's answer (yes, cluster it), but would add that to tighten your design, you might look a little deeper and consider making this a primary key, or if you can't, why not.  There's a nice writeup on the logic behind this on [this Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840162/should-each-and-every-table-have-a-primary-key)

Comment: The table posted has a primary key on the **Id** column.