# How to define Many to Many linking table

Tags: mysql

I have a schema with a store and product table. A store record, may have many products, and a product may be available to many stores (many to many) To link these, a third table has the PRIMARY KEY of the store, and product records. Should this linking table, have a compound PRIMARY KEY? Or, should this simply be two FOREIGN KEYS, each with an INDEX()?

```
CREATE TABLE store(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE product(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

So, should the linking table be like..

```
CREATE TABLE store_product_link(
  store_id INT NOT NULL,
  product_id INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX(store_id),
  INDEX(product_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Or should this be

```
CREATE TABLE store_product_link(
  store_id INT NOT NULL,
  product_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(store_id, product_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: It is always good to keep relationship with table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both, it should have a primary key and both foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE store_product_link(store_id INT NOT NULL, product_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(store_id, product_id),
FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product(id) ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: Why should it have a primary key?

Comment: @Bubinga see https://stackoverflow.com/a/840182/2131212