# Can I have a database table without PK if I know there will only ever be one record in that table?

Tags: c#, database-design, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am making a web app, and one of the db tables holds client information and design settings for the site:

```
public class Client
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string PrivacyStatement { get; set; }
    public bool HasLogo { get; set; }
    // some more properties
}
```

This table will never have more than one record, and it does not have any related tables. Is it ok to omit the PK in this case?

Comment: Sure - but why does it matter?

Comment: @mjwills I guess it doesn't really matter, but I don't like the idea of having something in the db that I will never use. I.e. the PK.

Answer (score 0):

Will the record will always be static  ?

If Yes, it is absolutely fine to omit the Primary key if you are 100% sure that this table will have only one record and also do not have any relation with other tables.(Why do you even want to store it in table? Think a bit)

If NO, then also you don't need to store it in a table simply store it in a object and change it accordingly.

There is also a nice discussion on this post about primary key you can look into it.

[Should each and every table have a primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840162/should-each-and-every-table-have-a-primary-key)

Comment: Some of the fields in the record will be dynamic. What is this object you are referring to? An object in the database?